# How to upload an external file by UIWebView on an iOS application?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am developing an iOS app and it pack the HTML5 site with UIWebView. Now it could upload images from the Photo Album and other files from "Browse" and iCould Drive.

Is there a way to let the app upload the external files from other apps? I have uploaded two screenshots as an example that opening the Notes file by another app - the Email app.

Can my app receive and upload an external file like this Mail app does?

[image]

[image]

Comment: UIWebView is obsolete and Apple will reject its use. You need too migrate to WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. If I use WKWebView, is there a way to upload external files?